# jquery dynmaically create iframe and populate these iframes to specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, iframe

so, basically what i need is... on my jsp , i set up for div to hold iframe which will be generated by jquery

```
<div class="tab-content shelf-content">
   <div class="iframe-content-1"></div>
   <div class="iframe-content-2"></div>
   <div class="iframe-content-3"></div>
   <div class="iframe-content-4"></div>
</div>
```

now in my js.  i created a loop, i wish to dynamically create 4 iframes and append them to div one by one, here is my code

```
function populateShelfItems(selectedAlphabet, selectedNumber){
    for (var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
        $('<iframe />', {
            src: '/item?alphabet=' + selectedAlphabet + '&numberCategory=' + selectedNumber + '&shelfNumber=' + i
        }).appendTo('iframe-content-'+i);
    }
}
```

but i got nothing show s up on the page....  all those divs are empty...

Comment: Why do you creating `iframe` twice in each iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Remove the extra `iframe` you are creating

2) In `appendTo` function you should specify a `class` to match your elements using `.` (dot), which you have missed

Change your code to:

```
function populateShelfItems(selectedAlphabet, selectedNumber){
    for (var i=1; i<=4; i++) {
        $('<iframe />', {
            src: '/item?alphabet=' + selectedAlphabet + '&numberCategory=' + selectedNumber + '&shelfNumber=' + i
        }).appendTo('.iframe-content-'+i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Please mark as answer in that case.